# Android Development: How an Android project be handled?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. Formally I am a Web Developer. My question is probably related to opinion. So I think I am going to get some stick here.

How an android project should be handled? I mean do you design all the screens first and then you start implementing functionality? or you go along with the screen design and also with it you implement the functionality?

Right now I have developed the UI designs and then I will develop the functionality.

It would really help me in adopting good habits.
Thank You

Comment: consider picking an answer if they helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your current position and I hope I will provide you good sequential steps right to proceed in your project according to my experience:

1) At first, be clear on the entire project that you are supposed to work.
2) Split your entire work into modules.
3) Now in the first module, pick up a screen. Design the module with .XML file and required Drawables.
4) Next start logical implementation so that you will have a clear understanding of the work done earlier on XML and current work on .Java file. Because of which I believe you will not miss the Sync and make necessary changes on the go in both XML and Java if required.

Pros: 1) You will have sync between XML and Java files due to which it saves considerable amount of time.
2) It also boosts up your confidence that you have completed one screen flow.
3) Without the creation of Java files simultaneously you cannot check the XML files created on the real devices, the feel of checking of real devices is great and different than checking it out on the preview screens.

Hope this adds up abit on to your knowledge and kindly upvote my friends if you too agree or follow the same.

Answer (score 2):

As an android developer I must suggest you to go through Google's official android tutorial site and start exploring things. Yes in android there is a layout file for making layout in `XML` and a java file for related code functionality and many supporting files for Images, Text Font, Style more.

Please look for training [here](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is best to start reading a book. Google's official android tutorial are great but i think that you can learn more from reading a book and after that going through the Google doc. I would suggest  Android 4 Application Development great book that covers all of the things you should know

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-4-Application-Development.productCd-1118102274.html